# I want to make a javascript autosubmit of a form that submits only once

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I am using a form that autosubmits when a page is loaded. The body tag looks like this:

```
<body onload="submitForm()">
```

the form tag looks like this:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://remote.url.com" method="POST">
```

and the javascript (placed in the header) looks like this:

```
function submitForm(){
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return false;
}
```

This works, but is for some reason submitting multiple times. I'm a beginner with JS, what can I put in the function to make sure it only works one time?

Comment: How is the javascript placed in the page?

Comment: Why exactly are you returning false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a form tag in your HTML but does it have an action attribute? something like this perhaps:

```
<form action='/somePageToGoToOnSubmit' method='POST'>
  ...
</form>
```

Without an action to take the user to another page upon submit, the form will submit to the same page (either by GET or POST depending on your method). This will result in a re-submission loop unless you either add an action to send the submission elsewhere, or perhaps deal with this server side.

Typically with forms I tend to configure the server to deal with the form submissions by POST which would then be handled by a method - and would typically redirect the user elsewhere, whilst having a separate method to deal with the GET requests used only to render the page. Or something to that effect.

Also, may I ask why you are immediately submitting your form on page load? - perhaps there is something you are trying to achieve that could be done slightly differently.

Comment: Yes it does have an action, that's why it's weird that it would be submitting multiple times. It could be something on the recipient's end. I work for a company that has to share information with various partners through their web forms. I load the data from our database and then load 5 separate iframes, each with one of these autosubmitting forms in it. This is a page that's only used internally of course I understand it's not great design.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints in your JS with a browser like Chrome and following the flow?

There could be some side affects from doing this across five frames. Does it do this redirect loop when all five frames are in play and does it still do it when only one iframe is operating (comment out the others)?

Comment: Yes in fact that's how I'm testing this. WHen this is eventually used it will be in an iframe but as of now I am only using this one form. I think it's something on their end really. Thank you for the help though.